# Hide logo when feature not available, uiview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a uitableviewcell which display a product and 5 logos or less, depending on if some feature is available or not for that product.

for exemple if the product has features a, b, c, d, e (on a b c d e), it should display :
a b c d e

for exemple if the product has features b, c and e (on a b c d e), it should display :
b c e

by doing removefromsuperview on the logo that are not to display, and doing a setFrame:CGRectZero, I have this :
"empty space"  b c "empty space" e
(I dont know how to do an empty space on this editor)

I can't find a way to have what I want. I can use a grayed icon if the feature is not available, but wanted to use only 3 logos when needed

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 5 UIImageViews to the button and fill them from left to right and set the not needed ImageViews-Images to nil.

Something like:

```
myCell.ImageView1.Image = imageB;
myCell.ImageView2.Image = imageC;
myCell.ImageView3.Image = imageE;
myCell.ImageView4.Image = nil;
myCell.ImageView5.Image = nil;
```

You could also use an array.

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray allo] init];

if (logo1IsNeeded == true) [arr addObject:imageA];
if (logo2IsNeeded == true) [arr addObject:imageB];
if (logo3IsNeeded == true) [arr addObject:imageC];
if (logo4IsNeeded == true) [arr addObject:imageD];
if (logo5IsNeeded == true) [arr addObject:imageE];

for (int i = arr.count; i < 5; i++)
{
   [arr addObject: nil]; //Fill the remaining entries with nil
}

myCell.ImageView1.Image = [arr objectAddIndex:0];
myCell.ImageView2.Image = [arr objectAddIndex:1];
myCell.ImageView3.Image = [arr objectAddIndex:2];
myCell.ImageView4.Image = [arr objectAddIndex:3];
myCell.ImageView5.Image = [arr objectAddIndex:4];
```

Please excuse if there are any typos in the code. I did this from mind.

Answer (score 2):

Add `ScrollView` in `UITableviewcell`. Fill `logo`(`imageView.image`) `horizontally` in `scrollView` if `logo` is `present`

arrayoflogo contains which logo u want to display

```
 for(int i = 0; i< [arrayoflogo count];i++)
 {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
        frame.origin.x = (i * 30) + (i * 5) + 5;
        frame.origin.y = 5;

        UIImageView *aimgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        [aimgView setTag:j];
        aimgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        //[aimgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        aimgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youImageName"]];
        aimgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.scView addSubview:aimgView];
        [aimgView release]; 
 }
```